# What does "exercise" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

This is a definition of the word "witchery" from the Oxford Languages dictionary.

> **witchery**
> compelling power **exercised by** beauty, eloquence, or other attractive or fascinating qualities

> **exercise**
> a. To make active use of; employ, apply, or exert: *exercise restraint; exercise control. *(source: American Heritage® Dictionary)

I knew this definition for exercise but I didn't know **beauty** could exercise power because beauty is an abstract concept and not a person and I thought this definition only extended to people. Was I wrong?

Comment: Why is the title about 'extend', which does not appear in your question?

Comment: Beauty, eloquence, and other attractive qualities are possessed by people, are they not? And they can give those people power, can't they?

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with being bewitched by someone's beauty?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with the word "exercise" used in this way and apparently I've had good reasons for it. Read the entire post with the answer if you want to know why:)

Answer (score 1):

That's a weak definition from Oxford.

Abstract concepts like beauty and eloquence themselves cannot exercise a compelling power because exercising a power is a deliberate, wilful action, and outside poetic senses, "beauty" cannot take deliberate actions. They can *be used* to exercise power, but that's not what it says, and a dictionary should be more precise.

It would be more accurate if it said, "*...exercised **using one's** beauty...*".